# How to correctly test one object on the page

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, capybara

I'm creating rails application with posts and likes.

```
feature "Create like" do
  include_context "user signed in"

  def have_updated_likes_count
    new_likes_count = bonus.likes_count
    have_content("Likes #{new_likes_count}")
  end

  let!(:bonus) { create(:bonus) }
  let(:decorated_bonus) { bonus.decorate }

  before { visit root_path }

  scenario "User likes bonus", js: true do
    find(".like").click

    expect(bonus).to have_updated_likes_count
    expect(page).to have_content(current_user.full_name)
  end
end
```

Bonus = post.  As u see here I check if User likes bonus. But in this root_path (main page) I have a lot of posts (20), and each of post has likes. My test trying to check `expect(bonuses).to have_updated_likes_count` and `expect(page).to have_content(current_user.full_name)` and it always true both, because it check full page, but I need to check only one post (where I did `find(".like").click`). How can I solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what your page structure is but generally you want to scope your actions to a specific element using `within`.

```
page.within('selector that finds the post element') do
  find(".like").click
  expect(bonus).to have_updated_likes_content   # issues
  expect(page).to have_content(current_user.full_name) # issues
end
```

That answers your question, however the rest of the test has a few issues you'll need to work out too.

1. Once you click the .like element the bonus object gets updated asynchronously, so trying to access it immediately is going to be flaky and you should really be checking for some other visual change on the page before checking it.
2. You're not reloading the bonus object from the database so it'll probably still have the same value